# How to integrate Admin LTE 3 in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, adminlte

How can i integrate adminlte 3 with Nuxt.js . I installed adminlte 3 with npm, then can I wrote css and js files in nuxt.config.js, styles working but js is not working, how to connect admin plugins to nuxjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file in the `plugins` folder: `plugins/myscript.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import MyScript from '../node_modules/myscript/myscript.js'

Vue.use(MyScript)
```

Then add the file path inside the plugins key of our nuxt.config.js:

```
export default {
  plugins: ['~/plugins/myscript']
}
```

More Infos [nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/)